# About TestNG @BeforeClass in multi@Test situation

Tags: testng, powermock, powermockito

I put initMocks and some PowerMockito init(each PowerMockito.when point to each @Test) in @BeforeClass.

But when run as TestNG test, just one @Test is success, the others is fail because these PowerMockito seems don't work.

Here is test code.

```
package main.test.testng.biz;

import main.java.testng.biz.Clazzname;
import main.java.testng.dao.Dao1;
import main.java.testng.dao.Dao2;
import main.java.testng.dao.Dao3;

import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Clazzname.class)
public class TestClazzname extends PowerMockTestCase {
    private Clazzname demo;
    @Mock
    private Dao1 dao1;
    @Mock
    private Dao2 dao2;
    @Mock
    private Dao3 dao3;

    @BeforeClass
    private void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(Dao1.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(dao1);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(dao1).set();
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Dao2.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(dao2);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(dao2).set();
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Dao3.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(dao3);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(dao3).set();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() throws Exception {
        demo = new Clazzname();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        demo.test1();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        demo.test2();
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() throws Exception {
        demo.test3();
    }
}
```

Here is tested code.

```
package main.java.testng.biz;

import main.java.testng.dao.Dao1;
import main.java.testng.dao.Dao2;
import main.java.testng.dao.Dao3;

public class Clazzname {
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test1");
        new Dao1().set();
    }

    public void test2() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test2");
        new Dao2().set();
    }

    public void test3() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test3");
        new Dao3().set();
    }
}
```

Here is class which invoked by tested code.

```
package main.java.testng.dao;

public class Dao1 {
    public void set() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Here is class which invoked by tested code.

```
package main.java.testng.dao;

public class Dao2 {
    public void set() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Here is class which invoked by tested code.

```
package main.java.testng.dao;

public class Dao3 {
    public void set() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Here is result.

```
test1
test2
test3
PASSED: test1
FAILED: test2
FAILED: test3
```

Do anyone know the reason?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: For example,<pre>
In BeforeClass {
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(dao).set(Mockito.any(bean.class));
}
In Test {
    fun() {
        dao.set(bean);
    }
}<code>

The success Test can ignore the dao.set, but the others step into dao.set.What I want is all the Test can ignore it.

Anyway, if I put mock init in BeforeMethod, it work!

Comment: @Monica - Can you please help share a full fledged example which can be executed to reproduce the problem ? Also if possible, please include the versions of mocks that you are using (maybe as a maven dependency). Include all this by updating your question.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - I use <groupId>org.mockito</groupId><version>1.10.19</version>, <groupId>org.powermock</groupId><version>1.6.5</version>, <groupId>org.testng</groupId><version>6.1.1</version>.
I supply the code above.

Comment: @JeroenHeier - I supply the code above.Just one of dao* inside the Demo.test* can doNothing according the mock rule, the others step into dao.set.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - Sorry, I use stackoverflow first time.

Comment: @Monica - There are still some classes that are missing. We cant execute the sample without all the classes being involved. Please help add all classes that are being referred to in `TestClazzname .java`. Please also trim it down to the bare essentials, so that anyone can copy paste it, run it to simulate the problem.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - Sorry, I supply the code above again. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: I think I find the reason.       PowerMockTestCase.afterPowerMockTestMethod: it clearMockFields.       PowerMockTestCase.beforePowerMockTestMethod: it injectmock from MockSettings.       So the mock in TestClazzname.beforeClass is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Following things need to be fixed in your test code:

- You need the mocking by powermock to be carried out before every `@Test`. So please change your `@BeforeClass` annotation and replace it with `@BeforeMethod`
- Your instantiation of the `Clazzname` can be done once per your test.
- You don't need the `RunsWith`annotation since you are not using JUnit here.

Here's the fixed code :

```
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@PrepareForTest(Clazzname.class)
public class TestClazzname extends PowerMockTestCase {
    private Clazzname demo;
    @Mock
    private Dao1 dao1;
    @Mock
    private Dao2 dao2;
    @Mock
    private Dao3 dao3;

    @BeforeMethod
    private void beforeMethod() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Dao1.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(dao1);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(dao1).set();
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Dao2.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(dao2);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(dao2).set();
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Dao3.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(dao3);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(dao3).set();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClas() throws Exception {
        demo = new Clazzname();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        demo.test1();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        demo.test2();
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() throws Exception {
        demo.test3();
    }
}
```